# how to disable scrollbar without overflow:hidden in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

**Is it possible to disable scrollbar without overflow:hidden in jQuery ?**

And without `$(window).bind("scroll", function() { scroll(0,0); });`

which works but the scrollbar is always active and it backs to top immediatly.

**UPDATE : Is there a way to put an PreventDefault() when a user click on scrollbar ?**

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want the scrollbar visible? And why are you doing this?

Comment: When I do `overflow:hidden`, my main div will move to the right (around 10px) because there is no scrollbar yet.

Comment: Then add a right-hand margin of 10px

Comment: Hmm... yeah but the scrollbar's width is not the same for each browser

Comment: Sorry, why is this so important? If your div is in the middle of the page use margin:0 auto; Otherwise use position:absolute; and position it relative to the left.

Comment: **UPDATE : Is there a way to put an PreventDefault() when a user click on scrollbar ?**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3342/discussion-between-steffi-and-tom-walters)

Comment: You really shouldn't fix layout problems with tricks like this, especially when they are confusing for the users. When people click on a scrollbar, they expect it to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way to do this from javascript ONLY, without setting the css param overflow:hidden (either manually, or from javascript). Why is it that overflow:hidden is not a good option for you?

Comment: then adjust it with padding, margin, or position:relative.

Comment: Hmm... yeah but the scrollbar's width is not the same for each browser

Comment: You can make the div's position absolute:  position:absolute;
 top: 140px;
 left: 87px;

Comment: **UPDATE : Is there a way to put an PreventDefault() when a user click on scrollbar ?**