# how to disable window scroll event down in jquery

Tags: jquery

In a html page i am calling a function at window scroll down in some cases i dosen't want to call window scroll down event(function)  then how can i dsable window scroll down event.
am using code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(), 
        docheight = $(document).height(), 
        winheight = $(window).height();
    var scrolltrigger = 0.95;
    if  ((wintop/(docheight-winheight)) > scrolltrigger) {
        //console.log('scroll bottom');
        add();
    }
});
```

Please help me if any one knows solution.

Comment: Just check if its changed from a global var and if so snap back to global var.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to disable scrollbar without overflow:hidden in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379032/how-to-disable-scrollbar-without-overflowhidden-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Use following code

```
$('body').on({
'mousewheel': function(e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'el') return;
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    }
})
```

You get good answer here -> [jQuery or Javascript - how to disable window scroll without overflow:hidden;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817899/jquery-or-javascript-how-to-disable-window-scroll-without-overflowhidden)

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/92mxb/

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this to snap back to origin. Something similar too this inside the `scroll()` function

```
if ( initScrollTop != $(window).scrollTop() ) {
    $(window).scrollTop( initScrollTop );
}
```

With the global being declared outside the function.

```
 var initScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
```

I'm on my phone and cannot test. Will be home soon, but it should be nearly that simple.